# I GET ( Index was outside the bounds of the array) ERROR

Tags: c#, luac

hey guys Im trying to make a injector but i am getting error

namespace AstromyJector
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(
          IntPtr hProcess,
          IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
          uint dwStackSize,
          UIntPtr lpStartAddress, // raw Pointer into remote process
          IntPtr lpParameter,
          uint dwCreationFlags,
          out IntPtr lpThreadId
        );

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(
        UInt32 dwDesiredAccess,
        Int32 bInheritHandle,
        Int32 dwProcessId
        );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 CloseHandle(
    IntPtr hObject
    );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(
        IntPtr hProcess,
        IntPtr lpAddress,
        UIntPtr dwSize,
        uint dwFreeType
        );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern UIntPtr GetProcAddress(
        IntPtr hModule,
        string procName
        );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(
        IntPtr hProcess,
        IntPtr lpAddress,
        uint dwSize,
        uint flAllocationType,
        uint flProtect
        );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
        IntPtr hProcess,
        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        string lpBuffer,
        UIntPtr nSize,
        out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten
    );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(
        string lpModuleName
        );

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    internal static extern Int32 WaitForSingleObject(
        IntPtr handle,
        Int32 milliseconds
        );

    public Int32 GetProcessId(String proc)
    {
        Process[] ProcList;
        ProcList = Process.GetProcessesByName(proc);
        return ProcList[0].Id;// THE ERROR SHOW ME FROM HERE
    }

    public void InjectDLL(IntPtr hProcess, String strDLLName)
    {
        IntPtr bytesout;

        // Length of string containing the DLL file name +1 byte padding
        Int32 LenWrite = strDLLName.Length + 1;
        // Allocate memory within the virtual address space of the target process
        IntPtr AllocMem = (IntPtr)VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, (IntPtr)null, (uint)LenWrite, 0x1000, 0x40); //allocation pour WriteProcessMemory

        // Write DLL file name to allocated memory in target process
        WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, AllocMem, strDLLName, (UIntPtr)LenWrite, out bytesout);
        // Function pointer "Injector"
        UIntPtr Injector = (UIntPtr)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

        if (Injector == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Injector Error! \n ");
            // return failed
            return;
        }

        // Create thread in target process, and store handle in hThread
        IntPtr hThread = (IntPtr)CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, (IntPtr)null, 0, Injector, AllocMem, 0, out bytesout);
        // Make sure thread handle is valid
        if (hThread == null)
        {
            //incorrect thread handle ... return failed
            MessageBox.Show(" hThread [ 1 ] Error! \n ");
            return;
        }
        // Time-out is 10 seconds...
        int Result = WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 10 * 1000);
        // Check whether thread timed out...
        if (Result == 0x00000080L || Result == 0x00000102L || Result == 0xFFFFFFFF)
        {
            /* Thread timed out... */
            MessageBox.Show(" hThread [ 2 ] Error! \n ");
            // Make sure thread handle is valid before closing... prevents crashes.
            if (hThread != null)
            {
                //Close thread in target process
                CloseHandle(hThread);
            }
            return;
        }
        // Sleep thread for 1 second
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // Clear up allocated space ( Allocmem )
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, AllocMem, (UIntPtr)0, 0x8000);
        // Make sure thread handle is valid before closing... prevents crashes.
        if (hThread != null)
        {
            //Close thread in target process
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
        // return succeeded
        return;
    }




    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String strDLLName = @"C:\Users\mraxe\source\repos\Test\x64\Debug"; // here you put the dll you want, only the path.
        String strProcessName = "Paintss"; //here you will put the process name without ".exe"

        Int32 ProcID = GetProcessId(strProcessName);
        if (ProcID >= 0)
        {
            IntPtr hProcess = (IntPtr)OpenProcess(0x1F0FFF, 1, ProcID);
            if (hProcess == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OpenProcess() Failed!");
                return;
            }
            else
                InjectDLL(hProcess, strDLLName);

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well, is a process with name `"Paintss"` running when you run this code?  Otherwise, `Process.GetProcessesByName(proc)` will return an empty array, for which accessing the first element with `ProcList[0]` would throw that exception.

Comment: oh i fixed its "Paintsss" thank you